# Losing line breaks when pasting code into Nitrous

Tags: ruby, ide, code, atom-feed

When pasting a bloc of Ruby code from Atom or the Nitrous text editor into the Nitrous console, all line breaks are lost. Multiple lines of code are concatenated into one long string, separated by a space where the line break was in Atom.

For example, if these three separate lines are copied from a text editor (either in Nitrous or Atom):
pool.each() do |number|
remainder_3=number.%(3)
remainder_5=number.%(5)

This is what Nitrous displays after pasting:
irb(main):001:0> pool.each() do |number| remainder_3=number.%(3) remainder_5=number.%(5)

Here is what I want to happen:
irb(main):001:0> pool.each() do |number|
irb(main):002:0> remainder_3=number.%(3)
irb(main):003:0> remainder_5=number.%(5)

The Ruby tutorial I'm watching retains line breaks when pasting so either my Atom or Nitrous settings need changing. Can someone please clarify how this is accomplished?

FYI: I'm running Windows 8.1 and Firefox. Note that I have this same issue using Chrome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: open txt file in notepad++. Add '\n' at end of line. Now paste.

Comment: @damon Thanks for the response. I added the \n tag to the end of each line but the text still concatenated. I think this might be an issue with the way Nitrous is set up. Do you have a preferred IRB for use with notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually use Nitrous. But here are some steps that you may find useful.

1) Write a random text with multiple lines in Nitrous.

2) Open that file in Notepad++.

3) Goto "View --> Show Symbol --> Show End of Line".

4) Find what symbol it uses as new line. You can find more about this [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

5) Now while writing any text that you wish to open in Nitrous, in place of **Enter** (Notepad uses symbol "LF") just place that symbol.

This is not very intelligent method , I accept. But this would do the job.